# Using D-Link D2750U Wi-Fi modem/router as a router only

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, modem

I recently bought a D-Link D2750U Wi-Fi ADSL modem/router, for my ADSL Internet connection.

But I have now changed my ISP, to one that provides Internet via cable (not telephone line). The ISP guy provides a cable modem (old modem) along with it.

I have connected my PC this way: Cable modem → Router → PC. I am able to access the Internet from my PC, but I am not able to get Wi-Fi working on the router. Please help in configuring the router to get Wi-Fi working. And I am logging onto the Internet through a dial-up connection. I did check the model details and it has WLAN enabled.

**Output of `ipconfig`**:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Narain-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

PPP adapter Yashtel:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Yashtel
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.200.114.14(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C8-60-00-C7-FB-4E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
                                       192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{512639CF-5EE2-4F6A-BA85-8002D82309C6}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:248b:9d3:5337:8df1(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::248b:9d3:5337:8df1%12(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{A64B7863-7938-4800-8C04-538AFD984077}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:acc8:720e::acc8:720e(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 2002:c058:6301::c058:6301
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Answer (score -1):

Acording to the [manual)ftp://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/ADSL/DSL-2750U/Description/DSL-2750U_User%20Manual_EN.pdf) - page 41 and 63, you can assign one LAN port to work as WAN connection.

Then, you just connect cable from modem to this assigned port and set the settings as your internet service provider said so (usually, in the IP settings you set dynamic IP address).

It is also useful to enable NAT service - that way you can use multiple devices in network under one WAN IP address.

Comment: I tried this:
1) Connected a LAN cable from cable modem to wifi modem and from wifi modem to PC
2) Thankfully, i am able use internet on my PC.

But i cant seem to get wifi working. Also, when i hit 192.168.1.1, its not displaying my dlink modem page. Please help

Comment: Can you open Command prompt (win8 http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/command-prompt-windows-8.htm Win7 - just click on start and write cmd then enter) and provide a output of  ipconfig /all command ?

Comment: OT: Next time, for long output, you can use pastebin.com

So, can you ping 192.168.1.1 ? What is the output? Again, do it in command prompt. What happened when you enter 192.168.1.1 into browser? 

Are you directly connected to router? Router <-> PC

Comment: ok, thanks. When i ping 192.168.1.1, i am getting a "request timed out".
And when i hit 192.168.1.1, it tries to connect for a long time and displays "couldnt connect message". Yes, I am directly connected to the router. Modem->Router->PC

Comment: Also, I just did a reset of modem and here is the output of ipconfig /all.[ipconfig](http://pastebin.com/aKwG4NY1#)

Comment: You did reset modem or router? Anyway, now try to ping 192.168.0.1 (as I see your IP address has changed) and type it to browser to see what happens. Basicly, you need to get to router configuration, that's why we are doing this...

Comment: Sorry, I meant reset of router. It again changed to 192.168.1.1. Now, I am able to see the router page. Please let me know what changes i need to do here. Thank you so much.

Comment: ugh, please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/704902/edit) your question and add the details, don't cram it into comments